# Finding records which might indicate fraudulent activities with SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-11

I have following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS auth_user
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR(30),
    first_name VARCHAR(30),
    last_name VARCHAR(30)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS statistics_restaccesslog
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id INTEGER,
    url VARCHAR(200),
    course_id INTEGER,
    date_visited TIMESTAMP,
    ip_address VARCHAR(16)
);
```

Consider below records:

```
INSERT INTO auth_user (username, first_name, last_name)
VALUES
    ('user1', 'John', 'Doe'),
    ('user2', 'Jane', 'Smith'),
    ('user3', 'Michael', 'Johnson'),
    ('user4', 'Emily', 'Brown'),
    ('user5', 'David', 'Miller'),
    ('user6', 'Olivia', 'Davis'),
    ('user7', 'Daniel', 'Wilson'),
    ('user8', 'Sophia', 'Anderson'),
    ('user9', 'Andrew', 'Taylor'),
    ('user10', 'Emma', 'Thomas');

INSERT INTO statistics_restaccesslog (user_id, url, course_id, date_visited, ip_address)
VALUES
    (1, 'https://example.com/page', 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '192.168.0.1'),
    (1, 'https://example.com/page', 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '192.168.0.2'),
    (3, 'https://example.com/page', 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '192.168.0.2'),
    (4, 'https://example.com/page', 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '192.168.0.3'),
    (5, 'https://example.com/page', 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '192.168.0.4'),
    (6, 'https://example.com/page', 2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '192.168.0.5'),
    (7, 'https://example.com/page', 2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '192.168.0.6'),
    (8, 'https://example.com/page', 3, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '192.168.0.7'),
    (9, 'https://example.com/page', 4, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '192.168.0.8'),
    (10, 'https://example.com/page', 5, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '192.168.0.9');
```

Point 1: Note the records with same combination of `(user_id, url)` for two different `ip_address`es:

```
    (1, 'https://example.com/page', 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '192.168.0.1')
    (1, 'https://example.com/page', 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '192.168.0.2')
```

Point 2: Note the records with same `ip_address` with two different combination of `(user_id, url)`:

```
    (1, 'https://example.com/page', 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '192.168.0.2')
    (3, 'https://example.com/page', 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '192.168.0.2')
```

I want to build SQL query which will return all such records. I tried following:

```
SELECT rat.id, rat.user_id, rat.url, rat.course_id, rat.date_visited, 
       rat.ip_address, u.username, CONCAT(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name) AS name
    FROM statistics_restaccesslog rat, 
        auth_user u
    WHERE ((url, user_id) IN (
        SELECT url, user_id
        FROM statistics_restaccesslog
        GROUP BY url, user_id
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ip_address) > 1
    ) 
    OR ip_address IN (
        SELECT ip_address
        FROM statistics_restaccesslog
        GROUP BY ip_address
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) > 1
    ))
    AND
    rat.user_id = u.id
    ;
```

On db-fiddle, it correctly returns first three records:

[image]

My real database have following records:

[image]

(The greyed out urls are exactly the same.)

However, when I run above query, it returns only first record, that is one with `id=17`. Record with `id=18` is not returned, even though it satisfies point 2. Why is this so? What I am missing?

**Update**

I have added four more records to `statistics_restaccesslog`:

```
-- same ip_address, two different (user_id, url)
(17, '/module1/api/rest1/', 1019, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '10.0.0.3'),
(18, '/module1/api/rest1/', 1019, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '10.0.0.3'),

-- same (user_id, url), two different ip_address
(19, '/module1/api/rest1/', 1019, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '10.0.0.4'),
(19, '/module1/api/rest1/', 1019, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '10.0.0.5');
```

First two satisfy point 2 and last two satisfy point 1. So all four records should appear in the query output. But they dont. The query output stays the same! I am not getting why these records are not coming in the output.

Also below is equivalent query with `JOIN`. It also results in similar behavior:

```
SELECT s.user_id, s.url, s.course_id, s.date_visited, s.ip_address, u.username, u.first_name, u.last_name
FROM statistics_restaccesslog AS s
JOIN auth_user AS u ON s.user_id = u.id
WHERE (s.url, s.user_id) IN (
    SELECT url, user_id
    FROM statistics_restaccesslog
    GROUP BY url, user_id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ip_address) > 1
)
OR s.ip_address IN (
    SELECT ip_address
    FROM statistics_restaccesslog
    GROUP BY ip_address
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) > 1
);
```

PS: Am using postgresql 11

Comment: Join is SQL Standard for 30 years now, you also should start to use them, for your problem use group by

Comment: Maybe there are null values in ip_address in statistics_restaccesslog? In this case `IN` won't work.

Comment: @PonderStibbons nope, there are no nulls in ip_address. I have added more info in "update" section of the question. I added four more records all of which should appear in the query output. But they dont !!! This might help in debugging the query.

Comment: New rows did not appear in the output, because there were no users with id 17, 18, 19. After adding them they appeared. [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ayZEonv8).

Comment: I made [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uXMg3cH6) where users are LEFT joined with statistics and instead IN it uses EXISTS clauses. I don't know if this will solve your problem, but it should handle cases with missing IDs and potential null URLs, IPs.

Comment: Advice: Use the inet data type for an ip address, not text/varchar. And having different ip addresses within a single http-session is pretty normal, I wouldn't call this network routing behavior fraudulent.

Answer (score 2):

Find the "keys" of the ip-address, resp. the user_id/url combination that matches the criteria using a GROUP BY Query and inner join that group by query back to the input table.

You need to formulate a clever `HAVING` clause:

- COUNT(*) > 1   AND ...
- MAX() <> MIN() of the differing information.

For a `user_id` >< `url` combination, you need to make a single expression of the two to make a MIN() / MAX() out of it. I used casting the `user_id` to `VARCHAR` and concatenating that with `url` .

I am almost completely sure you don't get the data you're looking for because there are no `auth_user` rows with the `id` as the `user_id`s returned from the two CTE-s.

To make my point, I left join the result tables to `auth_user`, and add the `user_id` column to the result table:

```
WITH
mult_usr_url AS (
  SELECT
    user_id
  , url
  FROM statistics_restaccesslog
  GROUP BY 1,2
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
     AND MAX(ip_address) <> MIN(ip_address)
)
,
mult_ip_addr AS (
  SELECT
    ip_address
  FROM statistics_restaccesslog
  GROUP BY 1
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
     AND MAX(user_id::VARCHAR(3)||ip_address) <> MIN(user_id::VARCHAR(3)||ip_address) 
)
SELECT
  s.id
, s.user_id
, s.url
, s.course_id
, s.date_visited
, s.ip_address
, u.username
, u.first_name||' '||u.last_name AS fullname
FROM statistics_restaccesslog s
JOIN mult_usr_url USING(user_id,url)
LEFT JOIN auth_user u ON u.id=s.user_id
UNION
SELECT
  s.id
, s.user_id
, s.url
, s.course_id
, s.date_visited
, s.ip_address
, u.username
, u.first_name||' '||u.last_name AS fullname
FROM statistics_restaccesslog s
JOIN mult_ip_addr USING(ip_address)
LEFT JOIN auth_user u ON u.id=s.user_id
ORDER BY 1
;
```

| id | user_id | url | course_id | date_visited | ip_address | username | fullname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | https://example.com/page | 1 | 2023-06-03 23:55:57.122415 | 192.168.0.1 | user1 | John Doe |
| 2 | 1 | https://example.com/page | 1 | 2023-06-03 23:55:57.122415 | 192.168.0.2 | user1 | John Doe |
| 3 | 3 | https://example.com/page | 1 | 2023-06-03 23:55:57.122415 | 192.168.0.2 | user3 | Michael Johnson |
| 11 | 17 | /module1/api/rest1/ | 1,019 | 2023-06-03 23:55:57.122415 | 10.0.0.3 | (null) | (null) |
| 12 | 18 | /module1/api/rest1/ | 1,019 | 2023-06-03 23:55:57.122415 | 10.0.0.3 | (null) | (null) |
| 13 | 19 | /module1/api/rest1/ | 1,019 | 2023-06-03 23:55:57.122415 | 10.0.0.4 | (null) | (null) |
| 14 | 19 | /module1/api/rest1/ | 1,019 | 2023-06-03 23:55:57.122415 | 10.0.0.5 | (null) | (null) |

Comment: I have added more info in "update" section of the question. I added four more records all of which should appear in the query output. But they dont !!! This might help in debugging the query. (Your query also does not return these four new records.)